# Remote GDB debugging - can't acces source file but no errors printed

Tags: debugging, gdb, embedded-linux, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I'm trying to remotely debug an application using GDB command line. 
Path in which gdb is run on the PC is the build path of the application. It contains the `amixer` executable and `amixer.c`.

The code is compiled with `-g -O2` parameters.

The debug symbols seem to be present:

```
$ readelf -WS amixer
There are 38 section headers, starting at offset 0x1d24c:
...
  [27] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 00a758 000140 00      0   0  8
  [28] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 00a898 008c59 00      0   0  1
  [29] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 0134f1 00085a 00      0   0  1
  [30] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 013d4b 001a8c 00      0   0  1
  [31] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 0157d8 000494 00      0   0  4
  [32] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 015c6c 001f75 01  MS  0   0  1
  [33] .debug_loc        PROGBITS        00000000 017be1 004dff 00      0   0  1
  [34] .debug_ranges     PROGBITS        00000000 01c9e0 000700 00      0   0  1
```

Steps on remote device (stripped binary):

```
gdbserver 192.16.6.21:12345 amixer
```

Steps on PC (binary here not stripped):

```
$ gdb amixer
(gdb) set sysroot /correct/path/to/remote/device/sysroot
(gdb) target remote 192.16.6.12:12345
(gdb) break main 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11f58
(gdb) list main   
(gdb) show directories 
Source directories searched: $cdir:$cwd
(gdb) continues
...program executes on remote device...
```

Assumptions I've made:

- `break main` doesn't throw an error so the executable debug symbols are available. I would expect to see the source file mentioned here already.  Like in [example](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Sample-Session.html#Sample-Session): `Breakpoint 1 at 0x62f4: file builtin.c, line 879.`
- there is `.debug*` in the output of `readelf -WS amixer` so the debug symbols are present
- `list main` doesn't list the source of the main function. Something isn't right
- `show directories` list `$cdir` and `$cwd` I'm guessing at least on of them is the directory from which I've started `gdb amixer` and that is the build directory with both executables and sources

I'm obviously doing something wrong so am looking for a review of the assumptions and debugging tips.

Comment: Does `addr2line -a 0x11f58 -e /correct/path/to/amixer-with-debug-info` show a filename and line number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> break main doesn't throw an error so the executable debug symbols are available.

You are mistaken: the fact that `break main` does not show any errors does *not* imply that debug symbols are available. And the rest of your output is consistent with debug symbols *not* being available.

So your first step should be to confirm that debug symbols are in fact present. If `readelf -WS amixer` does not show any `.debug_*` or `.zdebug_*` sections, that would be a proof that no debug info is present. If so, re-check your build command lines for presence of `-g` flag on compile lines, and absence of `-Wl,-s` or similar flag on the link line.

Comment: What does `0x62f4` in `Breakpoint 1 at 0x62f4` represent? I believed that was the memory location for `main` and because it's findable that means the debug symbols are available.

Comment: @Alan As I said, your binary *has* symbols, but not *debug symbols*. These are not the same thing (see also Mark Plotnik's comment).

Comment: Updated the question with new insights, the debug symbols do seem to be available. Am exploring the possible issues caused by the optimization `02` flag. Not really sure why it would default to both  `-02` and `-g` if optimization would cause debugging to stop working.